# Optmize the Co-Related SubQuery

Tags: sql

If we pass SourceDatabaseId, TargetDatabaseId. then we should get the database names. How can I optimize this Query

```
select (select database_name from t_database where id=dm.src_db_id) as source_db, 
(select database_name from t_database where id= dm.tgt_db_id) as target_db, 
(select count(*) from t_db_data_type_map where db_mapping_id = dm.db_mapping_id) as db_types_count
from t_db_database_mapping dm
```

Expected output:

```
| SouceDB | TargetDB   | TypesCount |
-------------------------------------
| Oracle  | PostgresSQL|   10       |
```

"QUERY PLAN"

```
"Sort  (cost=14473.29..14474.99 rows=680 width=252)"
"  Sort Key: dm.updated_dt DESC"
"  ->  Seq Scan on t_db_database_mapping dm  (cost=0.00..14441.30 rows=680 width=252)"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Index Only Scan using database_unique on t_database  (cost=0.14..4.16 rows=1 width=13)"
"                Index Cond: (id = (dm.src_db_id)::numeric)"
"        SubPlan 2"
"          ->  Index Only Scan using database_unique on t_database t_database_1  (cost=0.14..4.16 rows=1 width=13)"
"                Index Cond: (id = (dm.tgt_db_id)::numeric)"
"        SubPlan 3"
"          ->  Aggregate  (cost=12.88..12.89 rows=1 width=8)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on t_db_data_type_map  (cost=0.00..12.88 rows=1 width=0)"
"                      Filter: (db_mapping_id = dm.db_mapping_id)"
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: A couple of indexes should do the trick. Maybe they are not present. Please post the current execution plan to find out.

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.